# Unable to modify DateTime back to now

Tags: php, datetime

I have created a DateTime object modified it to go back 14 days ago and when I modify it back to today its not being modified.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
   $sql_query_date = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
   $sql_query_date->modify("14 days ago");
   $start_sql = $sql_query_date->format("Y-m-d");

   $sql_query_date->modify("now");
   $end_sql =  $sql_query_date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: Yes, Because it will work on the date you have set. So `now` mean the current date you have set not the today date

Comment: this is documented at http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 1):

`now` mean the current date you have set not the today date. So you need to recreate the date object or you can keep the modify value and revert them back.

```
   $sql_query_date = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
   $sql_query_date->modify("14 days ago");
   $start_sql = $sql_query_date->format("Y-m-d");
   print_r($start_sql);
   $sql_query_date = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
   $end_sql =  $sql_query_date->format("Y-m-d");
   print_r($end_sql);
```

OR

```
   $sql_query_date->modify("-14 days ago");
   $end_sql =  $sql_query_date->format("Y-m-d");
   print_r($end_sql);
```